# "make" command fails when building Snort from sources

Tags: c, linux, autotools, automake, snort

I am trying to install Snort from source.  I ran the "./configure" script.  It seems to work.  Subsequently the make command fails.

```
This command `make --trace` shows this:
Makefile:309: update target 'config.h' due to: stamp-h1 test -f
config.h || rm -f stamp-h1 test -f config.h || make  stamp-h1
Makefile:270: update target 'all' due to: config.h make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/snort_src/snort-3.0.0-a4'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'snort-3.0.c', needed by
'snort-3.0.o'.  Stop. make[1]: Leaving directory
'/home/ubuntu/snort_src/snort-3.0.0-a4' Makefile:270: recipe for
target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This command `make -p | grep AM_MAKEFLAGS` shows this:

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'snort-3.0.c', needed by
'snort-3.0.o'.  Stop.
@$(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) install-exec-am install-data-am
$(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) all-am
  && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) \
  && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) dvi \
  && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) check \
  && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) install \
  && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) installcheck \
  && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) uninstall \
  && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) distuninstallcheck_dir="$$dc_install_base" \
       && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) DESTDIR="$$dc_destdir" install \
       && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) DESTDIR="$$dc_destdir" uninstall \
       && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) DESTDIR="$$dc_destdir" \
  && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) dist \
  && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) distcleancheck \
@test -f $@ || $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) stamp-h1
$(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) $(DIST_TARGETS) am__post_remove_distdir='@:'
  $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) INSTALL_PROGRAM="$(INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM)" \
  $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) INSTALL_PROGRAM="$(INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM)" \
$(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) $(DIST_TARGETS) am__post_remove_distdir='@:' make: *** [all] Error 2
@$(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) install-exec-am install-data-am
$(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) all-am
  && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) \
  && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) dvi \
  && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) check \
  && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) install \
  && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) installcheck \
  && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) uninstall \
  && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) distuninstallcheck_dir="$$dc_install_base" \
       && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) DESTDIR="$$dc_destdir" install \
       && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) DESTDIR="$$dc_destdir" uninstall \
       && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) DESTDIR="$$dc_destdir" \
  && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) dist \
  && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) distcleancheck \
@test -f $@ || $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) stamp-h1
$(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) $(DIST_TARGETS) am__post_remove_distdir='@:'
  $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) INSTALL_PROGRAM="$(INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM)" \
  $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) INSTALL_PROGRAM="$(INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM)" \
$(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) $(DIST_TARGETS) am__post_remove_distdir='@:'
```

How do I get the `AM_MAKEFLAGS` to return a value?  The "make all-am" has only two arguments.  I believe it should have three.  It is as if the AM_MAKEFLAGS variable is empty.  I think that is why the "make" command is failing.

Comment: Maybe `autoreconf --force --install` followed by `configure` and then `make`.

Comment: This is not the right site for this question. voting to migrate.

Comment: What makes you think that `AM_MAKEFLAGS` should have a non-empty value?  I mean, maybe it should, but a `make` variable having an empty value is not uncommon, and `AM_MAKEFLAGS` in particular is rarely assigned a value.  You can think of it as a placeholder in the Automake framework where a package maintainer can plug in extra flags for `make`.  To a first approximation, people who are just *building* the package oughtn't to be concerned with it.

Comment: Nor should people be performing an `autoreconf` as a routine part of building Autotools packages.  You probably do need that if you find that you have to modify the build system, but you *do not* need it and should not perform it if you can get by with passing flags to `configure` and setting variables (on the command line) for `make`.

Comment: In any case, I had no such difficulty.  I downloaded [the source tarball](https://www.snort.org/downloads/snortplus/snort-3.0.0-239-auto.tar.gz), changed to its directory, and `./configure; make` did the right thing.  I'm inclined to guess, therefore, that there's something you haven't told us about what you did.